# Unable to save combobox selected index in database in C# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am able to bind the data from database to a `ComboBox`, but while trying to save selected index value back, it shows a `null reference error`.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindPAId();
    getPartyAccType();
}

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mode = "New";
    // getting error here 
    string AccTypeIndex = ddlAccountType.SelectedIndex.ToString();
}

public void getPartyAccType()
{
    // ddlAccountType.Items.Clear();
    PartyAccount objType = new PartyAccount();

    List<PartyAccount> ListType = objType.getAccountPartyType();
    ddlAccountType.DataSource = ListType;
    ddlAccountType.ValueMember = "AccTypeId";
    ddlAccountType.DisplayMember = "AccType";

    ddlAccountType = null;
    ListType = null;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why are you having this statement ? --  ddlAccountType = null; This causes your 'ddlAccountType' object to become null, when you access the SelectedIndex in ButtonClick event handler.

Comment: ddlAccountType = null; after removing this i am getting index values , if i make it null why then it shows data in combo box  not understood

Comment: You're combobox's databinding was complete and control was already rendered on your form before you set it to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a `NullReferenceException` is because you set the reference to `null` yourself. The problem lies within your `getPartyAccType`:

```
public void getPartyAccType()
{
    PartyAccount account = new PartyAccount();

    List<PartyAccount> accountPartyType = account.getAccountPartyType();
    ddlAccountType.DataSource = accountPartyType;
    ddlAccountType.ValueMember = "AccTypeId";
    ddlAccountType.DisplayMember = "AccType";

    //ddlAccountType = null;
    //accountPartyType = null;
}
```

There is no need to `null` the `dllAccountType` whatsoever. Nulling this means completely removing the reference to your component, which is not what you want. Also, you don't need to `null` the `accountPartyType` (`ListType` in your code) variable, the .NET garbage collector will remove the object from memory if needed; there is no need to do this yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply both Dinny and Jevgeni , accepting second one for reply there is no tick mark available to mark as Answer for first ans fro Dinny